# How to invoke method returning reference type properly?

Tags: java, methods, return, reference-type

I was going through the Oracle Java tutorials on the method returning the results of a reference type but had been stuck for quite a few hours. The link is provided here.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

```
public class Bicycle {

    private int speed = 0;

    public Bicycle(int a) {
        speed = a;
    }

    public static Bicycle seeWhosFastest (Bicycle bicycle1, Bicycle bicycle2) {

        Bicycle fastest = bicycle1;

        if (bicycle1.speed < bicycle2.speed) {
            fastest = bicycle2;
        }

        return fastest;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Bicycle firstBicycle = new Bicycle(100);
        Bicycle secondBicycle = new Bicycle(200);

        Bicycle.seeWhosFastest(firstBicycle, secondBicycle);
    }

}
```

However, I couldn't get it to work as intended. I was hoping to at least print out the `bicycle2` object but nothing showed.

Could you guys help me out here thanks in advance.

Comment: _I was hoping to at least print out_ How? Where do you do that? Why do you think that should happen? Why are you surprised that nothing showed?

Comment: Did you store the result of `Bicycle.seeWhosFastest(firstBicycle, secondBicycle);` anywhere when you tried to test this code?

Comment: @Pavlin hi there Pavlin so sorry I'm trying hard to learn here but I always get confused. Erm my assumption was that by invoking the method, it will `return fastest` and print out bicycle2 to screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that your static **seeWhosFastest** method returns a Bicycle reference type you can write:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Bicycle firstBicycle = new Bicycle(100);
        Bicycle secondBicycle = new Bicycle(200);
        Bicycle fastestBike = Bicycle.seeWhosFastest(firstBicycle, 
secondBicycle);
        System.out.println(fastestBike);
}
```

In order for this to print something significant you will need to override the toString method from your Bicycle class with something similar to @Makato's example

EDIT from your comments:

First add a second member variable to your Bicycle class something like:

```
private String reference;
```

and then add a toString method (also in your Bicycle class)

```
public String toString() {
    return reference;
}
```

Now update your bicycle constructor to something like

```
public Bicycle(int speed, String reference) {
    this.speed = speed;
    this.reference = reference;
}
```

Now change your main method as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Bicycle firstBicycle = new Bicycle(100, "Bicycle1");
        Bicycle secondBicycle = new Bicycle(200, "Bicycle2");
        Bicycle fastestBike = Bicycle.seeWhosFastest(firstBicycle, 
secondBicycle);
        System.out.println(fastestBike);
}
```

And it should work as expected

Hope this helps

Comment: hi there alainlompo i think of everyone's help here, yours is the closest to what my intention is. Thanks so much for your help! But what it prints out is the memory address of the object. is it possible to print out `Bicycle2` the object instead? :)

Comment: @Scorpiorian83 to avoid seing the memory address, just override the toString method from your Bicycle class a return significant informations. And to print something like Bicycle2 it's better to add a second field in the Bicycle class and gives it back through the toString method. Let me edit my answer

Answer (score 3):

You're not printing anything; all you're doing is mechanically computing the result of which `Bicycle` entity is fastest.

In order to see the result, you would need to do two things:

- Wrap the line `Bicycle.seeWhosFastest(firstBicycle, secondBicycle)` with a `System.out.println` call, and
- Implement `toString` in `Bicycle` so you don't get useless information.

The `toString` method is easy:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Bicycle, with speed " + speed;
}
```

Comment: hey hi Makoto thanks for your help! Why do we need to implement the toString()? I thought there is already default one? Another question is are we able to print out the object variable (bicycle2) instead of the speed variable of it? Thanks again!